# Representing found keywords in each search outcoming document in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with the below mapping:

```
"result": {
          "properties": {
            "duration": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "endTime": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "results": {
              "properties": {
                "offsets": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "output": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "startTime": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        }
```

I search for data in that with the below request body:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-5d"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "result.results.output": [
              "keyword 1",
              "keyword 2"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but I want to get the outcomings with an additional search-time field that represents found keywords list in each document.

I used the highlight option which highlights keywords in my result text that is 2 lines about but I only want the keywords that occur in that result.

EDIT:
I want to have outcoming as below (Considering I search for keyword-1 and keyword-2):

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "indx",
      "_id": "V3bd34YBoGQu2_2fF-La",
      "_score": 23.308632,
      "_source": {
        "result": {
          "results": {
            "output": "Text for test keyword-6 and keyword-2",
            "offsets": [
              3,
              4,
              6,
              7
            ]
          },
          "startTime": 1678793770.9358897,
          "endTime": 1678793772.0446372,
          "duration": 1.1087474822998047
        },
        "timestamp": "2023-03-14T11:24:25.942390",
        "found_keywords": [
          "keyword-2"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "indx",
      "_id": "V3bN34YBoGQu2_2fJ-GA",
      "_score": 7.1683946,
      "_source": {
        "result": {
          "results": {
            "output": "Text for test keyword-1 and keyword-3",
            "offsets": [
              0,
              6,
              9
            ]
          },
          "startTime": 1678792726.6787088,
          "endTime": 1678792727.4770997,
          "duration": 0.7983908653259277
        },
        "timestamp": "2023-03-14T11:07:01.381388",
        "found_keywords": [
          "keyword-1"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "indx",
      "_id": "I3bZ34YBoGQu2_2f6-I7",
      "_score": 6.0239806,
      "_source": {
        "result": {
          "results": {
            "output": "Text for test keyword-3",
            "offsets": [
              0,
              5,
              9,
              12,
              14
            ]
          },
          "startTime": 1678793563.2363102,
          "endTime": 1678793564.0036342,
          "duration": 0.7673239707946777
        },
        "timestamp": "2023-03-14T11:20:57.909010",
        "found_keywords": []
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "indx",
      "_id": "Jnba34YBoGQu2_2fFuKa",
      "_score": 5.947863,
      "_source": {
        "result": {
          "results": {
            "output": "Text for test keyword-2",
            "offsets": [
              0,
              5
            ]
          },
          "startTime": 1678793574.3921273,
          "endTime": 1678793575.1250415,
          "duration": 0.7329142093658447
        },
        "timestamp": "2023-03-14T11:21:09.015369",
        "found_keywords": [
          "keyword-2"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "indx",
      "_id": "VHbN34YBoGQu2_2fC-EM",
      "_score": 5.7249584,
      "_source": {
        "result": {
          "results": {
            "output": "Text for test keyword-1",
            "offsets": [
              0,
              5,
              11,
              12
            ]
          },
          "startTime": 1678792716.0380695,
          "endTime": 1678792719.9789963,
          "duration": 3.9409267902374268
        },
        "timestamp": "2023-03-14T11:06:54.097004",
        "found_keywords": [
          "keyword-1"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "indx",
      "_id": "pnbR34YBoGQu2_2f7-GV",
      "_score": 5.6651397,
      "_source": {
        "result": {
          "results": {
            "output": "Text for test keyword-1 and keyword-2",
            "offsets": [
              4
            ]
          },
          "startTime": 1678793040.0872865,
          "endTime": 1678793040.8126702,
          "duration": 0.7253837585449219
        },
        "timestamp": "2023-03-14T11:12:14.743225",
        "found_keywords": [
          "keyword-1",
          "keyword-2"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and I don't want to highlight keywords in the result of search.
I need something same to scripted_fields in search-time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to highlight search terms in the results.
You use the Term Field but not in the keyword field, which is the correct way.
If you want to filter, you should pass the complete search term, not just "keyword 1".
Below I made an example where the highlight will be applied when the search term is "keyword 1".

```
POST idx_index/_doc
{
  "result": {
    "results": {
      "output": "this is keyword 1"
    }
  }
}

POST idx_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "result.results.output": "keyword 1"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "result.results.output": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but No, I don't want to highlight keywords in results (my request search body used to do that already). I just get the found keywords in outcomings separately.